# Transistor Input ON Voltage

Tags: transistors, npn

I have this [BCR116 NPN Transistor](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BCR116SERIES-DS-v01_01-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30431428a37301143f60ae880285)

In the datasheet, they mention as Input ON Voltage instead of Base Emitter voltage like below :

[image]

But my doubt is, when they say Input ON Voltage is 0.5V minimum, since this part has an inbuilt internal resistors, does that 0.5V mean, that is before the series resistor or after the series resistor?

[image]

At which point are they mentioning that 0.5V should be? Before or After R1 in the above diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in more detail at the table: -

[image]

There are limits for Input ON voltage and Input OFF voltages. They tell you: -

- ON - to ensure at least 2 mA collector current for all the devices you might buy, you need to apply at least 1.4 volts.
- OFF - to ensure a collector current of less than 100 uA for all the devices you might buy, you need to apply less than 0.4 volts.

> *At which point are they mentioning that 0.5V should be? Before or
> After R1 in the above diagram?*

The pin called "B" is the input pin. There are no specifications for the actual base terminal of the internal transistor because it's "un-touchable" and internal.

Comment: Thank you. I want to calculate the input current that is required to turn on the transistor? So , If I apply 5V at the input pin of the transistor, how to calculate the current?

Comment: @Newbie page 4 shows the DC current gain for various temperatures. Alternatively you can assume that R1 is 4k7 (stated on page 1) in series with a base emitter diode of 0.7 volts. With 5 volts applied, a "B" current of 0.91 mA will flow.

Comment: OK thank you. But the base emitter diode voltage that you took is 0.7V. It is not mentioned in the datasheet, right? But we are taking it considering a normal PN diode,only right? So, this 0.91mA might be a near accurate estimate, right?

Comment: @Newbie I assumed that it uses a regular BJT and that, for a reasonable approximation, the BE junction will be around 0.7 volts hence current is 0.91 mA but it could be +/- 30% this figure. Alternatively work backwards from the current gain graph on page 4.

Answer (score 0):

It is of course the pin voltage (marked (1) on your picture).
In the same datasheet you find characteristics like:

[image]

and of course VBE cannot have a value like 10V in normal operation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: One doubt, how to find the base current, if I apply 5V at the pin 1 marked in my above image? Is it like (5-0.5)/3200 ?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to find the base current if the input voltage applied at the Point 1 as marked in my question is 5V ?

Comment: @Newbie Do you mean the base current, or the input current?

Comment: Oh, I thought only base current. Could you please tell me how to calculate the base and the input current of this transistor when I apply 5V at the point 1 marked in my above question?

Comment: And aren't the base current and the input current , same? What might be the difference?

Comment: The base current cannot be calculated as you said. You only can measure currents and voltages on pins and the value of R1 and R2 for instance are given in the datasheet in a given range not as an exact value. From you formula you are giving you still suppose that VBE is 0.5 and in the datasheet the base of the transistor is only mentioned for breakdown voltage and cutoff current. Vbe does not appear. Why are you interested in the base current?

Comment: Ok. I want to calculate how much current is required to turn on the transistor at its minimum turn on voltage. How to calculate that?